# How do you specify IP addresses for TravisCI's host addon?

Tags: travis-ci

According to [TravisCI docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/hosts/),

> If your build requires setting up custom hostnames, you can specify a
>   single host or a list of them in your .travis.yml. Travis CI will
>   automatically setup the hostnames in /etc/hosts for both IPv4 and
>   IPv6.

But it doesn't say anything of specifying IP addresses.  It also says nothing of the format for the host names.  Is is possible to specify a simple alias, like `myhostnamealias` or does it require a FQDN?  At least CircleCI mentions that it uses a FQDN (although I don't know why that stipulation exists, but that's a separate question.)

Thanks,
Robin.

Comment: This has been asked on https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5754

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the issue.  I'm surprised that it was answered so poorly and would indicate that you can't use DNS aliases on the Travis build host, which is pretty pathetic.  Circle CI has no such limitation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By experiment I have figured out that the list of hosts provided in

```
addons:
  hosts:
    - travis.dev
    - joshkalderimis.com
```

are all being set up to point to `127.0.0.1` equivalent to `/etc/hosts` entries like this:

```
127.0.0.1 travis.dev
127.0.0.1 joshkalderimis.com
```

Comment: I was testing this morning and set my hostname using addons: like above and set a hostname as local.dev, then in my bash scripts I run on Travis for testing my build I do a lookup on local.dev and it resolves as follows. ```Name: local.dev

Address: 127.0.53.53```